# Parametrize the line in the $R3$ which passes through the points

Tags: matrices, parametrization

The two points are:

$p =  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   -2 \\
   1 \\
   3
  \end{array} } \right]
 q= \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   5 \\
   -3 \\
   -1
  \end{array} } \right]$

The following formula that I used was
$r = p + tq$

However in the example they did $q-p$

$q-p = \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   7 \\
   -3 \\
   -2
  \end{array} } \right]$

Therefore I did $r =  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   -2 \\
   1 \\
   3
  \end{array} } \right]
+ t\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   7 \\
   -3 \\
   -4
  \end{array} } \right]$

The final answer I got was:
$x = -2+7t$
$y = 1 -3t$
$z=3-4t$

I am just wondering if this the correct procedure?

Comment: $r=P+tQ$ does not work because there is no value of $t$ which gives $r=Q$.  And when you tried the other method, you did not get the correct value of $Q-P$. You should also take care not to use the lower case and upper case of variables interchangeably.

Comment: my $q-p$ has been corrected. But would the second method be correct?

Answer (score 1):

One basic equation for a straight line in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n>1$ containing points $P$ and $Q$ is

$$ r(t)=(1-t)P+tQ\tag{1}$$

This gives $r(0)=P$ and $r(1)=Q$. For $0<t<1$, $r(t)$ is a point between $P$ and $Q$. For example, $r\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ is the midpoint of $PQ$.

Equation (1) may be rewritten as

\begin{equation}
r(t)=(1-t)P+tQ=P-tP+tQ=P+(Q-P)t
\end{equation}

Note that in your example, you still have the wrong value for $Q-P$. It should be

$$Q-P = \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   7 \\\
   -4 \\\
   -4
  \end{array} } \right]$$

Comment: After putting $Q-P$ into symbolab it gave me that value which is in my example. I am still unsure how you got $-4$ where I have $-3$  for $Q-P$

Comment: $5-(-2)=7,\,-3-1=-4,\,-1-3=-4$